# How to reorder columns in a dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm generating a `dask` dataframe with:

```py
b = (
    dask.bag.read_text(
       target_files,
       blocksize=None,
    )
   .map(_getdataframe)
   .to_dataframe(schema_dataframe)
)
```

Currently `_getdataframe` returns a `dict`. When I do `to_dataframe` the columns are essentially in a random order. Is there a way to either return an object that will result in a fixed column order from `_getdataframe` or cheaply resort the column order after the fact? Is the final column order dependant on the `schema_dataframe` I'm passing in or the `dict` result from `.map`?

Comment: You can always reorder the columns by smart indexing them: `b=b[['col1','col2',...]]`. You can even sort them alphabetically: `b=b[sorted(b.columns)]`.

Comment: An obvious possibility is to use `collections.OrderedDict` in `_getdataframe` instead of a standard dict.